# Reading Emails via IMAP / SMTP through 'Mail' gem

Tags: ruby, email

Is there a way to receive emails via IMAP or SMTP through the 'mail' gem?

The [documentation](https://github.com/mikel/mail) only seems to mention POP3:

```
Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "pop.gmail.com",
                          :port       => 995,
                          :user_name  => '<username>',
                          :password   => '<password>',
                          :enable_ssl => true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation actually talks directly about SMTP.

```
Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, address: "localhost", port: 1025
end
```

That is how you default to sending via SMTP.

To receive, instead of using `delivery_method` use `retriever_method`

Comment: I get this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for :smtp:Symbol` when I try to substitute `retriever_method` for `delivery_method`..  Thanks for looking into this though :)

Answer (score 0):

IMAP works by simply adding this:

```
Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :imap, :address    => 'imap.gmail.com',
                          :port       => 993,
                          :user_name  => '<username>',
                          :password   => '<password>'
                          :enable_ssl => true
end
```

I'm still not able to get SMTP retrieval to work..

Comment: That's because SMTP is for sending, not retrieving. POP3 or IMAP is what you should be using.